# JSP thinks my conditional is a block statement

Tags: java, sql, jsp

This is a snippet code for a little JSP servlet I'm writing to manage a PostgreSQL, which JSP claims is invalid.

```
<% if (request.getParameter("student-id") != null && 
    request.getParameter("sname") != null && 
    request.getParameter("date-of-birth") != null && 
    request.getParameter("email") != null && 
    request.getParameter("level") != null) {
        String update = "UPDATE students SET name = '" + request.getParameter("sname") + "', " +
        "date_of_birth = '" + request.getParameter("date-of-birth") + "', " +
        "email = '" + request.getParameter("email") + "', " +
        "level = '" + request.getParameter("level") + "' " +
        "WHERE student_id = " request.getParameter("student-id");
        statement.executeUpdate(update);
} %>
```

For some reason, this throws a nasty error at me complaining about a lack of a semicolon:

```
An error occurred at line: 65 in the jsp file: /students.jsp
Generated servlet error:
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
```

Line 65 is where I open the <%

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables strikes again.](http://bobby-tables.com) (It's even a table called "students"!)

Comment: Be glad of your typo on the `"WHERE student_id = " request.getParameter("student-id");` line (missing `+`), because now you know you have a **much bigger issue** you can easily solve (see above).

Comment: Andres: be really, really sure that you understand what T.J is saying here.    Your code has a major security problem.

Comment: Completely unsanitized input isn't the way to go, you say?! Thanks for pointing that out though, very new to the whole SQL thing.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

in this line you forget to put plus sign

```
"WHERE student_id = " request.getParameter("student-id");
```

and may I suggest `String.format()` as a better, clearer way to build the sql statement

Comment: Typos don't need *answers*, just close votes and (if appropriate) comments.

Comment: Jesus. I've been looking at this for too long. Thank you!

Comment: `String.format` is not a better way to build an SQL statement. Proper SQL parameters are a better way to build an SQL statement.

Comment: thanks, @AndresValdes, I found the bug for you and I got downvoted. the least you could do is accept and upvote.

Comment: Actually Sharon, suggesting that someone build an SQL query in a JSP using `format(...)` is really bad advice.  It is hiding an SQL injection vulnerability behind a layer of syntactic sugar. Please read TJ Crowder's "Bobby Tables" link.

Comment: I know about SQL injection. I was answering the OP question about compilation error. and suggested a more clear way of string concatanation in general (not specific to sql statements)

Comment: Read what you wrote in your answer: *"may I suggest String.format() as a **better, clearer way to build the sql statement**"*.  I doubt that the OP will understand the fine distinction between a terrible way, and a cleaner but still terrible way to compose a query.  Especially since you didn't point out the SQL injection problem/

Answer (score -1):

there is a missing '+' after where student_id="    at this place

```
<% if (request.getParameter("student-id") != null && request.getParameter("sname") != null && request.getParameter("date-of-birth") != null && request.getParameter("email") != null && request.getParameter("level") != null) { String update = "UPDATE students SET name = '" + request.getParameter("sname") + "', " + "date_of_birth = '" + request.getParameter("date-of-birth") + "', " + "email = '" + request.getParameter("email") + "', " + "level = '" + request.getParameter("level") + "' " + "WHERE student_id = "+ request.getParameter("student-id"); statement.executeUpdate(update); } %>
```